# Potential flaw with SBT's IO.zip method?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm working on an SBT plugin where I'd like to zip up a directory. This is possible due to the following method in [IO](http://harrah.github.com/xsbt/latest/api/index.html#sbt.IO%24):

```
def zip(sources: Traversable[(File,String)], outputZip: File): Unit
```

After tinkering with this method, it seems that simply passing it a directory and expecting the resulting zip file to have the same file & folder structure is wrong.. Passing a directory (empty or otherwise) results in the following:

```
[error]...:zipper: java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP file must have at least one entry
```

Therefore, it appears that the way to get use the `zip` method is by stepping through the directory and adding each file individually to the `Traversable` object.

Assuming my understanding is correct, this strikes me as very odd - vey rarely do users need to cherry-pick what is to be added to an archive.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Towards the bottom of IO's `writeZip` method, there are method calls to `addDirectoryEntry` and `addFileEntry` which imply that what I originally attempted should actually work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can use this to compose a zip with files from multiple places. I can see the use of that in a build system.

Comment: Hmm, I guess the key words here are 'build system'. Chances are if anyone is comfortable enough to be fiddling with SBT's guts, the `IO.zip` method probably isn't that much of an issue..

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but this should do what you need:

```scala
      val parentFolder: File = ???
      val folderName: String = ???
      val src: File = parentFolder / folderName
      val tgt: File = parentFolder / s"$folderName.zip"

      IO.zip(allSubpaths(src), tgt)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here  is  some code  for zipping  directories  using sbt's  IO  class:

```
 IO.withTemporaryDirectory(base => {
    val dirToZip = new File(base, "lib")
    IO.createDirectory(dirToZip)
    IO.write(dirToZip / "test1", "test")
    IO.write(dirToZip / "test2", "test")

    val zip: File = base / ("test.zip")
    IO.zip(allSubpaths(dirToZip), zip)

    val out: File = base / "out"
    IO.createDirectory(out)
    IO.unzip(zip,out) mustEqual(Set(out /"test1", out  / "test2"))
    IO.delete((out **  "*").get)
    //Create  a  zip containing this  lib  directory but  under  a  different directory in the zip
    val finder: PathFinder = dirToZip ** "*" --- dirToZip //Remove dirToZip as you  can't  rebase a directory  to  itself
    IO.zip(finder x rebase(dirToZip, "newlib"), base / "rebased.zip")

    IO.createDirectory(out)
    IO.unzip(base  /  "rebased.zip",out) mustEqual(Set(out /"newlib"/"test1", out  / "newlib"/ "test2"))
  })
```

See  the docs

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Mapping-Files.html

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Paths.html

for  tips  on  creating  the Traversable  object  to  pass  to  IO.zip